# nth-of-type not behaving correctly with targeting classes in list of different elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have an instance where I have an element with a class of `.card-one` and I want to apply a class to each even element. This works fine but I also have other divs with `.card-one` nested inside them and I do not want the those to be counted.

I tried to target the elements as direct descendants of the parent container using the css below but it is not working.

```
.all-cards > .card-one:nth-of-type(even){ color: red; }
```

Here is an example of whats happening. https://jsfiddle.net/sz5z4k58/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nth-of-type` selector doesn't refer to the *class*, but to the *type*, i.e. the *tag*, in your case the `div` and that *within its parent* element. So your nth-of-type selector actually selects every second DIV inside a parent if it has the specified class.

that's slightly confusing and not what one would expect from the name, but that's the way it works...